# Converting string value to hex decimal

Tags: c#, string, hex, decimal

i am making application in c#. In that implication i have string which contain decimal value as

```
string number="12000";
```

The Hex equivalent of 12000 is 0x2EE0.

Here i want to assign that hex value to integer variable as

```
int temp=0x2EE0.
```

Please help me to convert that number.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: int temp = int.Parse(number); The int variable will have the same value, whether you assign it a decimal number or a hexadecimal number. What you perhaps want instead is to get the hex string, such as: string hexStr = int.Parse(number).ToString("X");

Comment: check out http://www.geekpedia.com/KB8_How-do-I-convert-from-decimal-to-hex-and-hex-to-decimal.html

Comment: If you assign hex to an integer value it will always contain  binary.

Comment: Hasn't that question been answered multiple times on stackoverflow?

Comment: If you Change the Places of temp with number this will work like a charm .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An int contains a number, not a representation of the number. 12000 is equivalent to 0x2ee0:

```
int a = 12000;
int b = 0x2ee0;
a == b
```

You can convert from the string "12000" to an int using [int.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx). You can format an int as hex with [int.ToString("X")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx).

Answer (score 25):

```
string input = "Hello World!";
char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
foreach (char letter in values)
{
    // Get the integral value of the character.
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
    // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form.
    string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
    Console.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1}", letter, hexOutput);
}

/* Output:
   Hexadecimal value of H is 48
    Hexadecimal value of e is 65
    Hexadecimal value of l is 6C
    Hexadecimal value of l is 6C
    Hexadecimal value of o is 6F
    Hexadecimal value of   is 20
    Hexadecimal value of W is 57
    Hexadecimal value of o is 6F
    Hexadecimal value of r is 72
    Hexadecimal value of l is 6C
    Hexadecimal value of d is 64
    Hexadecimal value of ! is 21
 */
```

SOURCE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: A LINQ version, for when compactness matters more: `String.Join(" ", input.Select(char => String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToInt32(char))))`

Answer (score 6):

Well you can use class String.Format to Convert a Number to Hex

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(number);
string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
```

If you want to Convert a String Keyword to Hex you can do it

```
string input = "Hello World!";
char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
foreach (char letter in values)
{
    // Get the integral value of the character.
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
    // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form.
    string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
    Console.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1}", letter, hexOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert it to hex `string` you can do it by

```
string hex = (int.Parse(number)).ToString("X");
```

If you want to put only the number as hex. Its not possible. Becasue computer always keeps number in binary format so When you execute `int i = 1000` it stores 1000 as binary in `i`. If you put hex it'll be binary too. So there is no point.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this if its going to be int

```
string number = "12000";
int val = int.Parse(number);
string hex = val.ToString("X");
```